# Exclude newest document from a firestore query in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Basically as the title says - I am fetching documents from Firestore as per below but would like it to exclude the newest added document (otherwise it's showing on the page twice for me because of how I have it set up).

Is there anyway to achieve this?

```
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("Posts")
      .orderBy("timestamp", descending: true)
      .snapshots(),
```

to illustrate:

[image]

the main image is one stream which only shows the last added "Post", by timestamp. The three on the left are a separate stream which I'd like to not show the first one, as it's the same image. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "exclude the newest added document"? Can you please provide an example?

Comment: @AlexMamo I just added more info to the original post, does that make sense?

Comment: Why not check if the image already exists in the first stream and do not add in the second one?

Comment: @AlexMamo i'm not sure I understand what you mean by that. Both streams are fetching from the same collection

Comment: But are different streams, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo that's correct - that's what I'm not sure how to do

Comment: And you cannot compare the data of those two steams? In this way you can eliminate the data you don't want, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo I don't know how to do that, which is why I'm asking here :)